# How is load balancing not a bottleneck?

Tags: nginx, load-balancer

I've read a lot about how Nginx can be used as a load-balancer, and while there are plenty of other software options to use instead of nginx, isn't the concept of a load-balancer itself a bottleneck for all incoming requests? This picture is a pretty good example of what I mean: [bottleneck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tG36k.png). I realize redirecting the request is much faster than actually serving a response, but how many requests can a load-balancer like Nginx handle before it starts rejecting them? Because then it doesn't matter how many servers you have running behind the load-balancer. Is there like a meta-balancer and if so how would that work?

Comment: Apologies, but this question doesn't really belong here as its really just opinion. Yes, a loadbalancer can be a bottleneck (of-course, you can have multiple loadbalancers in parellel...).  The number of requests massively variable depending on the type of requests, if https is being terminated, the resources allocated to the proxy etc.

Comment: Depending on design/needs, you can have a cluster of load balances which can be balanced (crudely) at the DNS level so there are no overarching dependencies on a single balancer, or via routes/connectivity/routers.

Comment: Often, the limitations of a web site are Compute/disk io constraints. Load balancers can be set up so they use very little of either.

Comment: setting up a general purpose device running nginx may in fact slow things down, but please understand that most places that implement load balancing are going to be using specialized devices that have been heavily optimized for what they do, with additional hardware support for tasks like HTTPS offloading. Additionally meshes of load balancers are common, using network load balancers upstream, and layer7 load balancers closer to the application.

Comment: @davidgo if I have multiple load balancers, I still need one machine that can redirect the request to one of my load balancer, right, that will again create a bottleneck

Comment: @HimanshuPodddar Not at all.   There are lots of ways to distribute load without a single bottleneck - in my above statement, lets say you have 4 nameservers, each on a different IP.   Each nameserver can give out the IP address of a different load balancer.  Nameservers can (should) be on diverse IP's on diverse networks - and if you span multiple TLD's you have redundancy all-the-way to the TLD root.  (This is just 1 possible way to do it. BGP, multicast, redirects are other tools in the toolbox)